# JApplet in IE8/JRE1.6.0_24 -- NullPointerException on getAppletContext() & JSObject.getWindow()

Tags: java, html, applet, nullpointerexception

I have a JApplet I'm loading with JRE Plugin v 1.6.0_24 in IE8, and any time I try to use a callback to the webpage (ala getAppletContext() or JSObject.getWindow()) I'm getting an exception.  Basically it doesn't seem like IE is treating my JApplet as an actual applet because of the  tag maybe?  Either that or I'm doing something wrong in my JApplet.

Here's the HTML Object tag I'm using to embed the JApplet:

```
 <object codetype="application/java" 
     classid="clsid:CAFEEFAC-0016-0000-0024-ABCDEFFEDCBA"
     codebase="http://java.sun.com/update/1.6.0/jinstall-6u24-windows-i586.cab"
     width="640" 
     height="480" 
     id="ImageEdit">

   <param name="code" value="my.imaging.test.class"/>
   <param name="codebase" value="/folder/" />
   <param name="type" value="application/x-java-applet;jpi-version=1.6.0_24" />
   <param name="cache_archive" value="test.jar, jai_core.jar, jai_codec.jar,
                                       mlibwrapper_jai.jar, axis.jar, jaxrpc.jar,
                                       jbig2.jar, PDFRenderer.jar"/>
   <param name="cache_version"  value="1.0.2.F, 1.1.3, 1.1.3, 1.1.3,
                                        1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0"/>
   <param name="cache_archive_ex" value="test.jar;preload;1.0.2.F"/>
   <param name="cache_option" value="Plugin"/>
   <param name="scriptable" value="true"/>
   <param name="mayscript" value="true"/>
 </object>
```

Here's relevant portion of one of the JSException:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-4" netscape.javascript.JSException
      at netscape.javascript.JSObject.getWindow(Unknown Source)
      at my.imaging.test.lblLoadPageMouseReleased(test.java:2180)
      at my.imaging.test.access$6600(test.java:74)
      at my.imaging.test$15.mouseReleased(test.java:1621)
      at java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)...

Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
     at java.applet.Applet.getParameter(Unknown Source)
     ... 35 more
```

And the NullPointerException from getAppletContext():

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
      at java.applet.Applet.getAppletContext(Unknown Source)
      at my.imaging.test.lblCloseMouseReleased(test.java:2019)
      at my.imaging.test.access$6600(test.java:74)
      at my.imaging.test$15.mouseReleased(test.java:1621)
      at java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
```

So in my applet, obviously I'm extending javax.swing.JApplet and overriding init().  My callbacks take place on a mouse release event (as evidenced by the exception).

```
private void lblLoadPageMouseReleased(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {         
      JSObject window = null;
      URL url = null;                    
      try {
        url = new URL("http://127.0.0.1/folder/newpage.html");
        if (imageList.size() > 0) {
            if (JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(rootPane, "Are you sure?", 
               "Question", JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION, 
               JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE, infoIcon) == JOptionPane.OK_OPTION) 
            {
               this.getAppletContext().showDocument(url, "_self");
            }
        } else {
            window = JSObject.getWindow(this);
            window.eval("nextPage()");
        }
    } catch(JSException jse){
        jse.printStackTrace();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

I am stumped on this one.  Also, FYI -- I am not trying to run this from the command line and plugin.jar is on my classpath.  Any thoughts on what I'm doing wrong would be much appreciated... Thanks!

Edit:  SSCCE below

```
public class NewJApplet extends javax.swing.JApplet {

/** Initializes the applet NewJApplet */
@Override
public void init() {
    try {
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeAndWait(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                initComponents();
            }
        });

    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
private void initComponents() {
    btnDo = new javax.swing.JButton();
    btnDo.setText("Do Something");
    btnDo.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {

        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            btnDoActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });
    this.getContentPane().add(btnDo);
}

private void btnDoActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    URL url = null;
    try {
        url = new URL("http://127.0.0.1/folder/newpage.html");
        this.getAppletContext().showDocument(url, "_self");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
private javax.swing.JButton btnDo;
```

}

NullPointerException on this.getAppletContext().showDocument(url, "_self")

Comment: Instead of asking "Which line of appletImageMgt.java is 2019?", I'll instead suggest you prepare and post an [SSCCE](http://pscode.org/sscce.html).  Note that the first 's' means that no exception line would be anywhere near 2019.  An SSCCE should be possible within 100 lines of code (probably as little as 40).  Note also that other people will understand your code more easily if you stick to the common nomenclature for classes, methods & attributes.  This would mean `AllWordsUpperCase` for class names, `firstWordLowerCase` for methods and attributes and `SHOUTING_ALL_THE_WAY` for constants.

Comment: Holy Moly. Are you the same Andrew Thompson from [here](http://coding.derkeiler.com/Archive/Java/comp.lang.java.help/2005-05/msg00557.html)? You mentioned SSCCE there too! :)

Comment: Chris, do you see the same problem in Firefox or Chrome?

Comment: <object> tag won't render in FF, haven't tested in Chrome since it's an IE only application.

Comment: @Andrew Thompson -- added an SSCE.  And interestingly enough, I don't get an exception on that application.  I'm not sure what the issue is with the other applet since it runs just fine in the browser -- it just doesn't allow me to grab the context.

Comment: @Vivin Paliath  Yep.  That's me.  One thing that might help explain how often I mention an SSCCE is that I coined that abbreviation & am the 'document owner'.  ;)  @Chris Lohl  The 'trite' but inescapable conclusion is that the main applet is doing something differently to the example.  Find that difference & you have the solution.  BTW - are you **certain** that the exception points to the line with `getAppletContext()`?  There are other things in the original method that could be `null`.

Comment: If it does not throw the exception, it is not an example for the problem.

Comment: @Andrew Thompson - Yep the difference was in the auto-gen'd initComponents method. I wasn't even unfolding that method because I didn't think the IDE would bork me like that. Go figure. Thanks NetBeans! The other code - minus calls to some worker classes on button presses was basically identical.

Comment: @Paulo Ebermann: You are correct - not a proper example.  Had I copied in all the component initialization & the .form over from the other example I would have gotten the same results, though it would not have been "simple" and def not under 100 lines as my layout is VERY complex.

Comment: Thanks @Andrew for getting me thinking about the few places differences could be, and a big thanks to @Paulo to get me looking specifically for a null stub.  These comments got me to the right part of my code quickly this morning.  Now to figure out why NetBeans auto-gen'd that code in the first place -- and/or ditch it altogether...

Comment: @Chris: The trick is to minimize the example step by step (and test after each step whether it still shows the error). Make big steps first, but if some step removes the problem, undo it and make a smaller step (if you can't already see the problem here).

Comment: @Andrew: maybe your SSCCE document should contain some more indications on how to create them from a problematic program. In the TEX newsgroups I used to link to http://www.minimalbeispiel.de/mini-en.html (or the german version), but this is more LaTeX-specific, and does not apply easily to real programs.

Comment: @Paŭlo Ebermann I considered adding examples.  The problems are the length of the document, and it's specificity to Java.  1) The SSCCE document is already long enough that it can be difficult getting newbies to read it all. 2) It is already too specific to Java, I would like to have made it more 'language agnostic'.  But I'll consider making a separate page - '(Java) SSCCE examples'. @Chris Lohl  Glad you solved the problem.  :-)

Comment: @Paulo - Solid advice! And yes I should have known better... I really should have taken the time to whittle my code down as I usually do, but frustration and lack of understanding of the underlying browser-to-applet interface (e.g. the AppletStub) took over.

Comment: @Andrew - I admittedly had a "TL;DR" moment looking at your SSCCE doc, and made some (incorrect) assumptions of what you were after in my haste to post an example.  Feeling much more patient today, I took the time to -actually- read it.  It's a good, common sense methodology.  Glad you took the time to write it for people who rarely participate in forums like myself.

Comment: @Chris You're welcome.  But it was not entirely 'self sacrificing' of me.  I figured it would save a lot of *my* time in helping people to help themselves, and failing that, producing posts where I can easily examine problems. ;) Of course, I'm thrilled that so many other people think it is a good idea as well, and promote it widely.  Note of course, that it contained **nothing** original.  I figure the makers of the pyramids must have had similar thoughts - especially when their pyramids collapsed. ;)

Comment: @Andrew Haha, yes I do suppose the net result has been time saved on your part.  While the overall idea was nothing new exactly, it is good common practice even when not posting to a forum and (I thought) very logically written and explained without being condescending as many "forum posting" guides tend to be.  Plus it's always nice to have another acronym to throw around ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll do some guessing from the symptoms.

You have NullPointerExceptions in `Applet.getParameter` and `Applet.getAppletContext()`. Both these methods get the AppletStub and call the methods of this object. So my guess is your AppletStub is `null`.

Why can it be null? It can be null if your Applet is not the top-level Applet in the browser, but some component put inside another Applet.  Have a look at this.

Comment: This was EXACTLY the problem -- though not quite the cause you described. It appears that for some reason the NetBeans GUI editor added the following to my .form: 

<Property name="stub" type="java.applet.AppletStub" editor="org.netbeans.modules.form.ComponentChooserEditor"> <ComponentRef name="null"/> </Property> 

This in turn caused NetBeans to add the following line to my initComponents() method:
setStub(null);

Manually removed both entries in Notepad and magically I had working code.

Comment: I'm floored by the cause of the error.  I would not have suspected that even NetBeans* was that silly.  (* After seeing the invalid JNLP files that NetBeans produces - I have a rather low opinion of it.)

Comment: @Chris arrg! same problem here, on netbeans 7.1. just made me loose a day of work. Any al call to getProperty throws nullpointer exception. Netbeans autogenerates a "setStub(null);" in the initComponents section.